# The right way to write a vector to a binary file by iterator in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, ofstream

I have searched a lot for this type of questions but got no satisfied answers.

I am working on a function to write a vector container to a binary file using ofstream::write method in C++.

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

typedef std::vector<unsigned char> byteArray;

byteArray data;
data.push_back('a');
data.push_back('b');
data.push_back('c');
data.push_back('d');

std::ofstream fout("out_file", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);

// I know the right way should be as following:
fout.write((char *)&data[0], data.size());

// But what I cannot understand is why the following expression is wrong, since gcc compiler says
// invalid cast from type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char> >’ to type ‘char*’

for(auto iter = data.begin(); iter != data.end(); iter++)
{
    fout.write((char *)iter, 1);
}

fout.close();
```

As I understand, iterator iter is a pointer which points to one element in vector 'data'. So I think that (char *) iter would re-interpret the underlying data type as char, then it should satisfy the parameter requirement of fout.write. But actually, this is not the case. I am also very confused that gcc says iter is a type of iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector >, right? Should the iter not be unsigned char * type?

what do I get wrong? Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: _"As I understand, iterator iter is a pointer"_. No.  `std::vector::iterator` is an unspecified type.  If you need a pointer, you need `&*iter`.

Comment: Don't make assumptions about types. Even if you get it correct, the actual type may change over time as long as the behavior stays the same. That is why `C-Cast` is so dangerous it can hide errors because of assumptions.

Comment: I would not make the assumption that the array always holds 1 byte per character. If somebody changes the type of the array and forget to update the write it will silently break. `fout.write((char *)&data[0],  data.size() * size_of(byteArray[0]);`

Comment: Martin York is right, I should add size_of(byteArray[0]) within the fout.write function. great thanks. :) I should have a long way to go for C++.

Answer (score 2):

> As I understand, iterator iter is a pointer

It is not.  `std::vector::iterator` is an unspecified type.

You can expect it to have some pointer-like properties, but you should make no assumptions about what specific type it may be.

Since you need a pointer, dereference the iterator and take the address of that result.  That's a pointer.

```
fout.write((char *)&*iter, 1);
```

Better still, use C++ casts instead of the hard-to-track C casts.

```
fout.write( static_cast<char*>(&*iter), 1 );
```

Even safer (Martin York is always a precious gem) -- don't assume the size of the contained type.  It could change in the future.  This change adds no overhedd.

```
fout.write( static_cast<char*>(&*iter), size_of(byteArray[0]) );
```

Comment: Better yet don't assume the iterator points at a character.

Comment: This works well! Seems I am still too naive for taking an iterator as a pointer for granted. :-)

Comment: "*dereference the iterator and take the address of that result*" - note that if the type overloads the `&` operator, you will have to use `std::addressof()` to get the address, eg: `std::addressof(*iter)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau gross.  But true.  But gross.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer may be used as an iterator, but an iterator need not be a pointer.

An iterator behaves more or less like a pointer by providing operations for dereferencing `operator*()`, incrementing `operator++()`, etc., see requirements of e.g. [LegacyInputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator)

Although the concrete definitions change over time, see [std::input_or_output_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_or_output_iterator) for definitions in C++20.